# Do I need to encode encrypted bytes before sending?

Tags: encoding, hex, base64, encryption

Do I need to encode my encrypted bytes when sending it through java data streams for instant messaging? Sending encrypted bytes don't look very safe to me.

If so, should I use Hex or Base64 encoding?

Thanks

Comment: What problem with safety do you expect?

Comment: Which IM protocol are you working with? Jabber has a built-in encryption protocol.

Comment: I'm writing my own mobile phone chat system. The messages are sent through an SSL connection, but they have to be encrypted too.

In the code here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/PasswordMIDlet.htm , the author uses a HexCodec class to encode bytes into hex string before sending it. I am wondering whether I should also use something to encode them and whether this HexCodec class he uses is suitable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that its up to me. There is no real need unless I'm working with email protocols. Since I've implemented everything myself, its just a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

SSL already encrypts your data. Although the need may come up, encrypting data twice is usually unnecessary and consumes too much CPU time. This is especially relevant on mobile devices.

Comment: the second encryption takes place so that the server is unable to eavesdrop on the conversations.

Comment: why do you need SSL in the first place then?